# Add an <br> or <p> with createElement

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation, createelement

How can i add an `createElement(br)` before and after the table? I tried it with `doc.body.appendChild(p);` at the end, but nothing happens. i don't know where i have to write the `appendchild`

```
function insertBlock(border) 
{       
    var doc = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document;
    var p = doc.createElement("br");            

    var range = doc.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    myParent=document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.body;
    if (border == true)
    {
        myTable=document.createElement("table");
        myTable.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #000000;");
    }
    else
    {
        myTable=document.createElement("table");
    }
    // IE5, IE6 benoetigen unbedingt tbody-Element
    myTBody=document.createElement("tbody");
    myRow=document.createElement("tr");

    myCell=document.createElement("td");

    myText=document.createTextNode("Die erste Zelle");
    myCell.appendChild(myText);
    myRow.appendChild(myCell);

    myCell=document.createElement("td");
    myText=document.createTextNode("Die zweite Zelle");
    myCell.appendChild(myText);
    myRow.appendChild(myCell);
    myTBody.appendChild(myRow);
    myTable.appendChild(myTBody);
    myParent.appendChild(myTable);

    range.insertNode(myTable);

}
```

Comment: You mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/Laznwndc/1/)?

Comment: If you're doing this for spacing out elements then you're definitely taking the wrong approach. You should look at adding margin with CSS to achieve this. `<br />`'s should be a thing of the past. Also, with this amount of DOM manipulation, I would also try looking at a templating library like Handlebars. http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: That said, if you look at the comments in the code, they're targeting IE5, which is itself a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1):

Should be here:

```
myParent.appendChild(p);
myParent.appendChild(myTable);
myParent.appendChild(p.cloneNode());
```

Notice that the second one is a clone. When it's not. Only the second one will be added. (You can not add an element twice).

You can also add two different objects of course.

```
myParent.appendChild(p);
myParent.appendChild(myTable);
myParent.appendChild(p2);
```

Or withoud variables:

```
myParent.appendChild(doc.createElement("br"));
myParent.appendChild(myTable);
myParent.appendChild(doc.createElement("br"));
```

Comment: I tried on the beginnig of myParent and at the end. But the two br will add at the end, why?    myParent=document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.body; myParent.appendChild(p2); And at the end the same myParent.appendChild(p);

Comment: You do append a <br> before appending the table? Have you checked that p and p2 are actually set?

Comment: Do you have it somewhere online?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myTable.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<br />');
myTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin','<br />');
```

if you want to do it using `createElement('br')`.

```
var p = doc.createElement("br");            
myParent.insertBefore(p,myTable);
myParent.insertBefore(p.cloneNode(),myTable.nextSibling);
```

Comment: the add is after the end and not before

Comment: you want it after end and befor begin ?

Comment: i tried but i get only at the end of table the break

Comment: Which one does that? Because both adding after and before the table in the edited answer